# Order by(условия сортировки)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть у меня числа от 0 до 23 (int) нужно чтобы их **order** как время (точнее часы)
т.е. чтобы считало  21 22 23 0 1 2 3 4 и т.д.

пока получается вразнобой. может кто сталкивался. Заранее благодарю

Comment: Приведите таблицы с данными и что вы хотите получить на выходе. порядок. по вопросу не понятно со скольки часов вы хотите начинать отсчет. Вообще просто придумываете арифметическую формулу которая вытащит с нужного часа в начало

Comment: к примеру у меня 2 смены. 1-я с 8 до 20 00
т.е должно выбирать 8 9 10 11 12 ... 20
2-я с 20 до 8 т.е 20 21 22 23 0 1...8

Comment: Возможно, пригодится финт - добавление несуществующего десятка. То есть 8 часов первой смены - это 8, а второй - 38. Подобную систему использовал при  подготовке сеток тв-программ, когда начало дня - раннее утро, а конец - поздняя ночь.

Comment: Как вы это храните? Таблицу приведите пожалуйста. Смена -- это не только время, но и дата, поэтому 21:00 01.01.2016 < 01:00 02.01.2016

Comment: Пусть количество часов колонка 'n', тогда `order by (1-sign(n/8))*24+n` даст требуемую сортировку. Но лучше дату хранить как дату в временем и возможно проблем будет меньше

Comment: история длинная)) я использую отдельную таблицу в которой хранятся числа от 0 до 23 (часы)(smallint). их потом я join с другой таблицей с условием Datepart(время из другой таблицы) = час из таблицы с часами. хранить дату и время не получиться в данном контексте

Comment: order by (1-sign(n/8))*24+n а что это за формула?

Comment: Ну вы попробуйте. она ко всем значениям от 0 до 7 добавляет 24, остальные оставляет без изменений. таким образом все значения до 8 часов при сортировке окажутся после 23

Comment: ну она не до конца работает теперь сортировка для 2-й смены (20 до 8) выглядит  8 9 21 22 23 0 1 2...7 (не обращайте внимания на 9 часов так нужно по условию)

Comment: Поэтому я и говорю, приведите таблицу с данными. Я пробовал на таблице с числами от 0 до 23. она дала как вы просили 8-23, 0-7 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8c6f2/1

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: 0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23

вот все данные с таблицы (smallint)
ее join с другой (по datepart)

почему оно 8 ставит перед 21?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так?

```
select * from
        (values(1),(2),(3),(0),(21),(22),(23),(6),(7),(9)) T(id)
        order by case when id>20 then 1 else 2 end, id
```

Answer (score 1):

Введите дополнительное поле для уточнения сортировки:

```
SELECT Time FROM
(
 SELECT 0 AS Time, 2 AS Shift
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 1 AS Time, 2 AS Shift
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 9 AS Time, 1 AS Shift
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 10 AS Time, 1 AS Shift
) s
ORDER BY Shift, Time
```